# Does GCP Kubernetes Autopilot support zero downtime update?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, autopilot

First of all, I use a GCP k8s **standard** cluster, which works fine.
I am a bit interested in **autopilot**, so I tried to deploy the same pods on a k8s autopilot.

The thing is, I got many 502 errors when rolling updates pods implemented in Go Gin and Python FastAPI(uvicorn). Go is less 502 errors than Python.

I doubt that Service(ClusterIP) correctly switches traffic across pods during rolling update.

Again, the same applications works fine with the **standard** version, and preStop, maxSurge, and graceful shutdown in Go and Python are implemented as the following doc says. Is there any settings that are specific to **Autopilot**?

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing#traffic_does_not_reach_endpoints

Comment: Can you use something like readiness probe with Autopilot ? If the 502 are temporary, the addition of the readiness probe could make it wait for the new pods to be in ready state for X seconds before redirecting trafics. In addition, Autopilot uses the "same" Kubernetes as with standard under the hood, it's just hidden to the final user, there shouldn't be a difference between cluster ip service in autopilot mode and in standard.

Comment: Yes, readiness probe is implemented correctly, and as I mentioned, it works well in the standard k8s, traffic won't hit until the app is ready to accept requests.